# Change image while ImageButton is pressed

Tags: xamarin.android, imagebutton

I have one ImageButton in my android app, and I'd like the app to change the image while the button is pressed, and when the user release the button it returns to the default image.

P.S. I'm using mono for android and I have to do this programatically, I can't use the XML tag unfortunatelly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can hook into the views's [`Touch`](http://docs.mono-android.net/?link=E%3aAndroid.Views.View.Touch#) event to do that:

```
var button = FindViewById<ImageButton>(Resource.Id.MyImageButton);

button.Touch += (object sender, View.TouchEventArgs e) => {
    if (e.Event.Action == MotionEventActions.Down) {
        button.SetImageResource(Resource.Drawable.Icon);
    } else if (e.Event.Action == MotionEventActions.Up) {
        button.SetImageResource(Android.Resource.Drawable.IcMenuGallery);
    }
};
```